# Submit form live via new jQuery - without .live

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, live

I had problem with submitting live form on new jQuery (1.10.X, 2.X). I need form populate through handlebarJS and show form in modal window. 
Because function .live() doesn't exist anymore.

Old method:

```
$("#form-xyz").live('submit', function(e) {  .... } );
```

This doesn't work:

```
$("#form-xyz").on('submit', function(e) { .. } );
```

This work:

```
$(document).on('submit', "#form-xyz", function(e) { .. } );
```

Do you know better solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior for `on()`.

`$("#form-xyz").on('submit', function(e) { .. } );` probably doesn't work because `form-xyz` is added to the DOM after the handler is bound. If you need to use dynamic elements with `on()`, you'll need to use a delegated event listener, which is what you did in your second example.

You can read more about this in the [documentation for direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).